# Access a function in a separate module using typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am migrating a Nodejs project from JavaScript to TypeScript and I keep getting this error from the code that worked earlier in JavaScript. I have some functions defined in a separated module, I want to access this function from a function in another module depending on the arguments passed to the function.

`schemas/users.ts`

```
export const signup = () => {}
export const signin = () => {}
```

`schemas/index.ts`

```
import * as UserSchemas from './users';

export { UserSchemas }
```

`validate.ts`

```
import * as schemas from './schemas';

const validate = (schemaCollection: string, schemaName: string) => {
  const schemaFunc = schemas[schemaCollection][schemaName];

  // Use the schemaFunc in the code following this line.
}
```

If the `validate` function is passed called like this: `validate('UserSchemas', 'signin')`, I want to get the `signin` function back. I get this error when I run the code:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof import("...schemas/index")'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof import("...schemas/index")'. ts(7053)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is basically saying that your typing of `validate` is too lenient, for example `validate("Does", "not exist")` is valid, but `schemas[schemaCollection][schemaName]` will throw an error/return undefined.

The correct way to circumvent this is either a union of literals (or enums), or generics:

```
const validate = <T extends keyof typeof schemas, K extends keyof typeof schemas[T]>(schemaCollection: T, schemaName: K) => {
  const schemaFunc = schemas[schemaCollection][schemaName];

  // Use the schemaFunc in the code following this line.
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=8&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBwAsCmBbAhhGBeGBvGA9ATAEIYCWwaANtQJ4xTIzkoAOIATrFHW0gFgAUDFEwAqhCScAyolQYAXHmFi1ccgHMwAVzbKAFAEpsAPjwwAvgBpV60RC1hyYQyazn8lu6O9C-wqCQsABuNOQAJmhQSNgwADwAKjBIAB4xYBGYANZIdCAAZox8SIVw8ugQ1jAA0inpSJk5eWW8-GXwyJUA2okAuqYGnQoAwiC0SMBQ5ODKidXD6AByaChIyjXunnZB0OVdaABiOmDAcYsY3RdjE1MzYH1XFWgra30A3MJ2RBJSjMwXY6nFhgf6xUARWIFcbUEAAdxcmn+5Ew1BcSAAdMI-EA)

> Although, if this function uses user supplied data in any way, hard code the possible paths or thoroughly validate the input before using this since this is only a compile-time measure and does not protect you from a user entering invalid information and crashing your application.